# Issue in deploy Angular Universal App to Vercel

Tags: angular, deployment, vercel, universal

I am trying to deploy my angular universal app to vercel, I have been following [this](https://dev.to/jdgamble555/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-to-vercel-31d0?comments_sort=latest#toggle-comments-sort-dropdown) article on dev.to but i am getting the following error while deploying the app.

this is my configuration but i am getting errors as show below.

[image: Image description]

api/index.js

[image: Image description]

vercel.json

[image: Image description]

package.json

[image: Image description]

[image: Image description]

using Angular V17

Please let me know on how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Angular universal is sort of deprecated. It's to say, It's now embedded in angular itself. You can create a new app, and the CLI will ask if you want ssr too. However you can still install and configure `@angular/platform-server` manually. But actually after creating a new angular app with ssr, all you need to do after deploying is run `npm run start`